# Helpe me to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as mostView FROM users RIGHT JOIN visitors ON users.id = visitors.user_id GROUP BY users.id HAVING users.isActive=1 AND users.fullName IS NOT NULL AND users.photo_id IS NOT NULL AND users.role_id IN(1, 3) ORDER BY mostView DESC LIMIT 5
```

It works, but I need convert to Laravel eloquent, i'm using laravel 5.6, could any one helpe me thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did you get any errors?

Comment: No I do not try. i'm new in laravel but good in sql and php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember you are expected to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of what you are coding and the errors you are experiencing. The main idea is you get your feet wet first and then discuss what the problem may be. There's a lot of good resources you may find by googling and even right here at StackOverflow to learn the basics and not-so-basics of Laravel. Eloquent is frequently discussed. Did you try looking it up before asking?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have map the relationship in your Model if you do you can do like below,

```
$userViews = User::->with('vistors')
->where('isActive',1)
->whereNotNull('fullName')
->whereNotNull('photo_id')
->whereIn('role_id ',[1,3])
->get();

$mostView = $userViews->sortBy(function ($collection) {
   return  $collection->vistors->count()
})->take(5)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not going to spoon feeding but can provide you some ideas to convert raw sql to eloquent, your sql should ideally be like this:

```
User::selectRaw('*', 'count(*) as mostView')
    ->rightJoin()
    ->groupBy()
    ->having()
    ->where // whereNotNull // wherIn
    ->orderBy()
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

Kindly refer to laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all i'm studies Database: Query Builder on the link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

and so i solved my question by myself 
the answer is:

```
$mostViews = DB::table('users')
->rightJoin('visitors', 'users.id' , '=' , 'visitors.user_id')
->select('users.*', DB::raw('count(*) as mostView'))
->where('isActive', '=', '1')
->whereNotNull('fullName')
->where('photo_id', '<>', 'NULL')
->where(function ($q){
    $q->where('role_id', '=', '1')
    ->orWhere('role_id', '=', '3');
})
->groupBy('user_id')
->orderBy('mostView', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```